# Vercel cannot get a data from json. Angular

Tags: angular, get, vercel

I have this error :

```
 message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/assets/data/trending-movies.json: 404 Not Found"
```

in console.

In local environment I have no problem when subscribing to data stream:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getTrangingMovies()
    this.getTheatreMovies()
    this.getPopularMovies()
  }


  getTrangingMovies() {
    this.http.get("http://localhost:4200/assets/data/trending-movies.json").subscribe((movies) => {
      this.trendingMovies = movies;
      console.log("Trending Movies: ", this.trendingMovies)
    })
  }
```

I did nothing but it was working in local environment

Comment: Are you really willing to get your trending-movies.json file from port 4200 ? 4200 is the default port for local developement. If you want to download from the same domain from project assets, you might try to change your code for `this.http.get("/assets/data/trending-movies.json").subscribe(...)` (path relative to root).

Comment: aww, I will try this one thanks